# Find out an app's URL programmatically

Tags: ios, url, url-scheme, bundle-identifier

I need to launch another app from within my own app, but I don't have its URL. So my question is:
Is there a way to find out another app's url programmatically based on its bundle identifier, or trackid?

Comment: what you want " launch another app ?"  can you elaborate it ?

Comment: I need to launch another app from within my own app

Comment: If you know the app at compile time you should also know the scheme at compile time

Comment: That's my problem, I don't know the app, I'm receveing information on what app to open from a server.

Comment: Do you have any assurance that the app you want to open is even installed on your user's device? What should happen in case it's not?

Comment: No, I didn't have any assurance the app was installed. I ended up just using a store kit popover which has an `open` button, and when the app is not installed, it just gives the user the option to install it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to determine an app's custom URL scheme programmatically. An app's custom scheme, if there even is one, can be completely unrelated to anything else you may know about the app.

The only way to determine the scheme is to access the app's Info.plist file, and unless you are on a jailbroken device, this can't be done at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to launch other apps, you can use ios private api.

```
@interface PrivateApi_LSApplicationWorkspace
    - (bool)openApplicationWithBundleID:(id)arg1; //LSApplicationWorkspace
    - (NSArray*)privateURLSchemes; //LSApplicationWorkspace
    - (NSArray*)publicURLSchemes;
@end

PrivateApi_LSApplicationWorkspace* _workspace;
_workspace = [NSClassFromString(@"LSApplicationWorkspace") new];
[_workspace openApplicationWithBundleID:bundleIdentifier];
NSArray* privateUrls = [_workspace privateURLSchemes];
NSArray* publicUrls = [_workspace publicURLSchemes];
```

check https://github.com/wujianguo/iOSAppsInfo