# get all iOS url schemes on device

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Is there a way to get all the url schemes of all the apps on a device? There has to be a central repository of them somewhere, maybe a plist?

Comment: I don't think this is a dup, I am trying to generate a list in my app of all available url schemes on the device. The app is a sales tool and we're trying to link it to two other apps we've built - but some people might not have them installed. That post was just looking for url schemes to other apps like facebook

Comment: Why not just check if you can open that URL before doing it? `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:@""];`

Answer (score 15):

Adding my solution in case someone is still looking. After spending some time researching the answer, I finished off on a mix between @danielbeard's and @Avis' solution.

Because I know what application I am looking for:

1. Download the .ipa from iTunes using my computer
2. Copy the application to my desktop
3. Rename it to *.zip
4. Extract the *.zip
5. Open the 'Payload' folder
6. Right click on the application and select 'Show Package Contents'
7. I then double-click the 'Info.plist' file (which Xcode should then open)
8. Then check 'URL types' > 'Item 0' > 'URL Schemes'

Using that information I then add it to an array of apps to check (doing what @danielbeard suggested).

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: The correct one is not necessarily located in item 0 within "URL types"

Comment: Since iTunes 12.7 came out back in Sept 2017, you can no longer access apps via iTunes on the computer.  Once again, Apple has fundamentally changed they way a critical component of their whole ecosystem works.   This should probably be updated.

Comment: @rolinger You can get the app with Apple Configurator 2
https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/download-ipa-files-for-ios-apps-your-iphone-0184056/

Answer (score 2):

if it's programatically, i don't know.

here is answer to related to your question(not exactly)

[Find out an app's URL programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380530/find-out-an-apps-url-programmatically)

But manually, on your device-

yes...

there is a way to get url schemes of all apps on your device by this procedure. Install ifunbox on your system. Connect your device, open user applications and open the app that you are trying to find url scheme. you will find app home folder, in that folder you will find info.plist of that app. open info.plist and check url scheme address in the last column.

it worked for me. you will find url scheme of some apps which are registered for url schemes.

here are some some links for url scheme addresses of some apps.(might save your time).

1.http://handleopenurl.com/
2.http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Comment: I need to do it programmatically. Building an enterprise app and looking to see if some related apps are installed.

Comment: how can you find related apps? you mean based on url scheme or functionality. i'm confused url schemes of app or something like passwords. how can you find functionality of app based on url scheme? @PruitIgoe

Comment: both links are broken

Comment: Trying to use iFunBox. It seems that since iOS 8.3, this procedure requires either that the app has enabled iTunes File Sharing, or that the device is jailbroken. Now what? I want to find schemes for apps that don't have this enabled, and that are not jailbroken. And I don't have a phone with iOS < 8.3.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment. I found this: https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/download-ipa-files-for-ios-apps-your-iphone-0184056/
You can now get the app using Apple Configurator 2. No need for a jailbroken device or iTunes File Sharing. However, this method makes use of the app store's app update process. Therefore you have to already have the app, but an old version that needs updating. Then you can use this to pull down the .ipa for the updated version.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use private api. First

```
@interface PrivateApi_LSApplicationWorkspace
- (NSArray*)privateURLSchemes;
- (NSArray*)publicURLSchemes;
@end
```

then use it:

```
PrivateApi_LSApplicationWorkspace* _workspace;
_workspace = [NSClassFromString(@"LSApplicationWorkspace") new];
- (NSArray*)privateURLSchemes
{
    return [_workspace privateURLSchemes];
}

- (NSArray*)publicURLSchemes
{
    return [_workspace publicURLSchemes];
}
```

check https://github.com/wujianguo/iOSAppsInfo.

Comment: To save you some research time, this solution does NOT WORK since iOS 11.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a whim here and assume you are trying to do the following:

1. You have a PDF in your app.
2. You want to check (programmatically) to see if any other app can open PDF files.
3. If so, open PDF using that app.

If you want to do this, you don't have to do step 2 manually. As a matter of fact, you can't. However, you can use the [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) class to present a menu of compatible apps.

This is the only way you can "check" for other apps installed on the phone. At least on iOS 7 and under.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported officially by Apple API without jailbreaking

A workaround might be how Bump knows which apps are launched and support URL Schemes: 
http://danielamitay.com/blog/2011/2/16/how-to-detect-installed-ios-apps

Comment: That's closer but you have to either know the url scheme of the app or see the app running on the device (a user doesn't close it but it sits in background). I already know the url schemes of the apps I am looking for (they are apps we control already) but I just wanted to see if I could do it programmatically.

Comment: The reason you can't do tyat lookup programmatically is it's a security feature that apple implements, mainly sandbox for each app. If all apps knew you installed other apps (schemes) it would be considered a risk, fingerprinting you to a bank, paypal, or password app for example.