# Navigate to LinkedIn-Learning iOS app from an iOS app using URL Scheme

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, linkedin-api

On clicking the link of a LinkedIn-Learning URL from an iOS App it should open the LinkedIn-Learning iOS App if installed on the iPhone.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is the URL scheme used to open the LinkedIn-Learning iOS app?
I have tried using "linkedin-learning" under  LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in Info.plist

Comment: it may not have one.  But you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672362/get-all-ios-url-schemes-on-device

Comment: Thanks, Will try that and let you know.

Comment: You can try to download the .ipa file and search into the info.plist,  the corresponding key of  URL scheme is `CFBundleURLSchemes`, you can find it if there is one.

Comment: @ShamSundarC - First make your description clear. From where you want to open Linkedin-Learning app?

Comment: I downloaded the .ipa file and extracted the Info.plist file and I found that the URL Scheme used as "lilearning" for linkedIn-Learning app.
I have used the same and works like charm in the iOS app.

Comment: @ShamSundarC Can you please mark the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to find the `URL scheme` of an iOS Application is to download the `.ipad` file and search into the `info.plist`, the corresponding key of `URL scheme` is `CFBundleURLSchemes`. You can find it if there is one.

Then you can use this `URL scheme` to open the corresponding app.

Answer (score 0):

To find the URL Scheme mentioned in any of the iOS application just download the .ipa file using "Apple configurator 2". After downloading the .ipa file, we should extract the Info.plist file from it then look for the key name "URL types"
[please check here for the image for LinkedIn-Learning app's Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utalK.png)